# cannot resolve module (inserting pic from source imgs folder)

Tags: reactjs

I've downloaded an image (shape) then copied the image from the downloaded location to a folder called `Footer.JS`.

My directory structure is `Source/assets/Home/Footer.JS` (`Footer.JS` is a directory even though it looks like a file).

When I try to add the image of a shape I get the error of "cannot be resolved". What is going on?

```
import React from 'react'
import './Footer.css'

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className= 'footer-container'>
      <div className='footer-parent'>
       <img src={require('../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png').default} alt='no connect'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Why is my module not able to be resolved?

```
I have edited my code to this but still nothing


     import React from 'react'
import shape from '..\..\..\src\assets\Home\shape-bg.png'






export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className= 'footer-container'>
      <div className='footer-parent'>
      <img src={shape} alt= 'no connect'></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is the error

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/Portfolio_container/Home/Footer/Footer.js 5:0-58

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '......srcassetsHomeshape-bg.png' in 'C:\Users\codat\Desktop\my-portfolio\src\Portfolio_container\Home\Footer

Comment: This depends entirely on the bundler/toolchain you're using. Use `import`, in any case...

Comment: i have imported everywhere it need to be

Comment: I mean, you're using `require()` – try `import`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `src` instead of require like that

```
import Shape from '../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png';
```

and

```
<img src={Shape} alt="no connect" />
```

if you still want to use require you can create a variable that has the path:

```
let Shape= require('../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png');
```

Comment: I am a beginner so forgive me,  so the first line "import" would go  a top of my Footer.js  file  then  the second line would replace the line of code ? just being clear, because I've done this and it is not working either .

Comment: yeah exactly, always imports at top of the file, and replace ur image component with this